# Events doesn't occur if the window is not displayed

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I use `setTimeout` to perform some animation on a page.

When the page is not visible in the browser, animation is postponed until the window get the focus.

- Why ?
- Can I change this default behaviour (I want that the animation
  occurs, even if the window is not visible) ?
- is it related to : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Timeouts_in_inactive_tabs_clamped_to_%3E1000ms

The aim is to perform some automated tests with `WebDriver`, and unfortunately it works with Firefox but fails with Chrome.

Comment: You need to use a different approach to accomplish that, there is a reason why it that way.

Comment: @xxxmatko how is that comment supposed to be helpful? Clearly he knows he needs a different approach... thus the question. Saying, "there is a reason why it's that way." is not informative and is pretty much useless. If you know why, then say so... if not, then why state the obvious?

Comment: The way you have this phrased, this doesn't seem like a Selenium question... it seems like a javascript question. Is that what you intended? Are you asking about fixing the animation or how to automate it? Please clarify.

Comment: At the end of the animation, I update the global state. I want to be able to test that. I don't know how : javascript side or selenium side.